# Expand all items on Jface FilteredTree when filtertext is empty

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

i'm a bit lost, with the following problem.  I'm using a class which expands "org.eclipse.dialogs.FilterTree". When the filtertext is empty every node in the tree is collapsed. But i want expand the Tree when this is the case.

Can anybody, please give a hint? Whats the best way to do this? I've overriding various methods so far, but with no success.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expand all the tree using `TreeViewer#expandAll()`

> **Edit 1:**
>
> The `FilteredTree` refreshes the tree on every change to the filter text control, but with some delay (by default 200ms). So adding a modify listener on text control for expanding all tree will at the time show a different set of items (maybe none) and later the refresh job will overwrite the state using its own rules. So either we need to override `doCreateRefreshJob()` to expand all tree in case of empty string, or override `updateToolbar(boolean)` which is always called at the end of the refresh job. this is what I tried and it worked:

```java
FilteredTree ft = new FilteredTree(composite, SWT.FULL_SELECTION, p, true) {
    @Override
    protected void updateToolbar(boolean visible) {
        super.updateToolbar(visible);
        treeViewer.expandAll();
    }
};
```

Comment: I know, but where should i call that method? And when? For example: I have overriden the method "doCreateFilterText". There i call the method of the parent class, but then add a ModifyListener. In it's modifyText - Method, i checked if the FilterText is empty and than called TreeViewer#expandAll() => didn't work.

Comment: @Patrick it would be really useful if you can add the code in your question. I would be able to make a better suggestion.